# Binding photoswipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I am trying to bind photoswipe so that it continues to work even if a div is loaded, has anyone done this before or can tell how to do this?

I tried changing the

```
galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
```

line to a binding on click statement to #container. This worked until i clicked off the slideshow which then killed all other click events on the page and left a thumbnail stuck in the middle of the screen. any ideas?

Here is the photoswipe JS:

```
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

    // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements
    // (children of gallerySelector)
    var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
        var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
            numNodes = thumbElements.length,
            items = [],
            figureEl,
            linkEl,
            size,
            item;

        for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

            figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

            // include only element nodes
            if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                continue;
            }

            linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

            size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

            // create slide object
            item = {
                src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
            };



            if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                // <figcaption> content
                item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML;
            }

            if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
            }

            item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
            items.push(item);
        }

        return items;
    };

    // find nearest parent element
    var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
        return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
    };

    // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
    var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

        // find root element of slide
        var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
            return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
        });

        if(!clickedListItem) {
            return;
        }

        // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
        // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
        var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
            childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
            numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
            nodeIndex = 0,
            index;

        for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
            if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) {
                continue;
            }

            if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                index = nodeIndex;
                break;
            }
            nodeIndex++;
        }



        if(index >= 0) {
            // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
            openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
        }
        return false;
    };

    // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
    var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
            params = {};

        if(hash.length < 5) {
            return params;
        }

        var vars = hash.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            if(!vars[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');
            if(pair.length < 2) {
                continue;
            }
            params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        if(params.gid) {
            params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
        }

        return params;
    };

    var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
            gallery,
            options,
            items;

        items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

        // define options (if needed)
        options = {

            // define gallery index (for URL)
            galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
                var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
                    pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect();

                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }

        };

        // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
        if(fromURL) {
            if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                // parse real index when custom PIDs are used
                // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    if(items[j].pid == index) {
                        options.index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // in URL indexes start from 1
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
            }
        } else {
            options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
        }

        // exit if index not found
        if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
            return;
        }

        if(disableAnimation) {
            options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
        }

        // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
        gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
    };

    // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
    var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

    for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
        galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
    }

    // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
    var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
    if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
        openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
    }
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a small wrapper for PhotoSwipe in jQuery that lets you use dom elements to convert to gallery. It also does not require you to define image dimensions, just autodetects by itself. Check it out.

https://ergec.github.io/jQuery-for-PhotoSwipe/